# Facebook API Friend Location object being returned with empty string for id and null for name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, friend

Yesterday, when I retrieved my Facebook Friends from the Graph API using the query "me/friends?fields=id,location" 500+ came back with location data.

Today, 500+ are returned with the location object, but only 36 have any data in the location object, the rest are returned as:

```
"location": {
    "id": "", 
    "name": null
}
```

You can reproduce it yourself in the Graph API Explorer.  You'll see that some friends have legitimate locations, but the majority have the null values.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on?  This happened to happen the same day Graph Search was announced.  Is it related?  How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**: Facebook has updated the status of the bug that I posted to "Fix Ready" so this should be resolved shortly... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487611667944115

Comment: Added a bug here. Please help if you were able to reproduce: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487611667944115

Comment: I'm having the same issue, drove me nuts for a minute looking through my own code.

Comment: If you find a friend with a null location using the /me/friends call, and do a call to pull their profile individually (using their id and the graph api) the location data gets returned properly, with actual data--not to say that this should be the behavior, as this is definitely inconsistent with how the /me/friends call should work--but it could hold you over until facebook gets around to fixing itself.

Comment: Facebook has updated the status of the bug that I posted to "Fix Ready" so this should be resolved shortly... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487611667944115

Answer (score 1):

As Zachary mentions, it is probably a facebook bug. However they marked the bug as 'medium' priority and could take forever to fix. If you need to get yourself up and running quickly again, switch to an FQL call instead. The following correctly returns location data for all your friends:

```
SELECT name, uid, current_location FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

If you're also looking for hometown info, though, then tough luck. Seems like the bug mentioned also affects FQL in this case...

Comment: Tried this, but similar result. Instead of Location id being empty, it's not even a field beyond the first 63 friends out of 400+ in my case.